# Managing IDs in an asynchronous world

Tags: database, identity, data-synchronization

When a new record can be created at potentially any number of locations (i.e. different mobile devices), how do you guarantee that record a unique identity?

(In my SQL-steeped worldview, the default type of an ID is an int or long, though I gladly consider other possibilities.)

The solutions I've considered are

1. Assign each device a pile of IDs which is (hopefully) more than they will use between syncs, and replenish it when syncing.
2. Assign each newly created record a temporary ID (Guid) until it can be assigned a "real" ID by the System of Record.
3. Use Guids as IDs.
4. Block the creation process until the ID is provided by the System of Record (not preferred due to possible network interruption).
5. Use a primary value (e.g. Name) as an ID (also not preferred due to potential of primary value to change).

These are what I've come up with on my own, but since this is the type of problem that has certainly already been solved ten million times, what are the accepted solutions?

Comment: I just wonder - why do you need an ID before it is assigned to you by the underlying persistence layer?

Comment: If I need data and relationships between records to persist on the remote device, I need IDs, right?

Answer (score 1):

You could have an unique id for each device (could be set during initial on-line registration), and each device would do its own numbering. The records themselves would use composite primary key: (originDeviceId, recordId), which then is guaranteed to be unique across all devices and has several other advantages, like no need for changing the key when syncing with server and ability to use that key to build relations on off-line remote device right from the start.

The main downside is that you need two columns to reference the record. A - bit hacky - workaround would be to have those columns defined as ints and another - computed one - as a big int, made out of those previous two. The downside is no leftshift operator in most RDBMS, but it can be solved using multiplying by power of two. Then you just make relations using that computed field, so for example:

```
SELECT file.* FROM t_File as file
JOIN t_User as user on file.UserId = user.Id

-- t_File.UserId is big int and t_User.Id is deviceId * POWER(2, 32) + recordId
```

Another downside is limiting your records to max int, which might or might not be enough in your case, but at least you have guaranteed uniqueness.

Last downside I see is a need for that initial registration to get assigned an unique device id.

Comment: Interesting idea, but I'm really hoping to solicit some "Here is what we did", or even better, "Here are standard practices"-type solutions since it seems like a pretty common situation.

Comment: Sure ;) I never have seen this kind of a problem by myself, out there unfortunately. I'd bet though that using GUIDs is the most common practice - they are well supported by the SQL Server and other RDBMS and they are virtually unique. Depending on your data structure I'd probably create - in addition to uniqueidentifier PK - clustered index on the creation date though, as I don't think that physically ordering by random number is all that useful ;)